# Creating a function that makes an inversed matrix

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell and would like some ideas on how to create a function that would take every head element of multilist's lists and add it to a new multilist, then move on to second column and etc.. So far I only know how to write a function for the first column: `inverted (xss) = map head xss` How to make it to go until it does it with every column of a multilist?

Comment: Please don't call this “inversed” matrix, that's way too similar to [inverse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) which is something quite different. As Silvio said, the correct term is [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_of_a_linear_map#Representation_as_a_matrix).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can write this function directly, and you've got the exact right idea to start with. Get the heads first, and then make a recursive call.

Assuming all of the lists are of the same length,

```
inverted :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
inverted [] = [] -- Degenerate case
inverted xss
  | null (head xss) = []
  | otherwise = map head xss : inverted (map tail xss)
```

As it happens, this function is already in the standard library: it's called [`Data.List.transpose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) and it does exactly what you want.